# Writing a loop that has multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to replace values in a column based on certain criteria. Here is my code:

```
   For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(i) = "w" Or "x" Or "y" Or "z" Then

            .Item(i) = "A"

        End If                 
    Next i
```

If the value in the cell is w, x, y, or z, I need it to equal "A". This loops works if I do each character individually but how would I go about combining the criteria together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to use an array input for this; you can easily alter the array then but the code will still work. Something like:

```
Dim arr() As String: arr = Split("w,x,y,z", ",")
For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If .Item(i) = arr(j) Then .Item(i) = "A"
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: All answers worked and I wish I could give you all the check. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, but as you're almost there yourself I'll present the option that closest matches your attempt:

```
If .Item(i) = "w" Or .Item(i) = "x" Or .Item(i) = "y" Or .Item(i) = "z" Then
```

instead of your existing IF. This is the correct way to use `Or` for these decisions.

Alternatively, a slightly slicker way that is easier to expand (and read) would be simply to look for an occurrence of the search item in a longer string. I've separated the matches with a `|` separator in case the cell contains for example `xy` and you don't want that to match. You may want to change the separator if there is a chance that it might be used in your table.

```
If InStr(1, "w|x|y|z", .Item(i), vbBinaryCompare) Then
```

Change the `vbBinaryCompare` to `vbTextCompare` if you don't want it case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Select case would be my preferred method here

---

```
For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
     Select Case .Item(i)
         Case "w", "x", "y", "z"
             .Item(i) = "A"
         Case "something else"
             'If you have other criteria
         Case Else
             'If you have a action item for something that isn't any of the above
     End Select
 Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) will perform this quickly.

```
dim repl as variant, i as long

repl = array("w", "x", "y", "z")

for i = lbound(repl) to ubound(repl)
    activesheet.range("A:A").replace what:=repl(i), replacement:="A", _
                                     lookat:=xlwhole, matchcase:=False
next i
```

Comment: replace method can actually be very slow if there are many replacements and/or calcs are set to automatic and the workbook has a bunch of formulas.

Comment: Perhaps, but still faster than looping through each cell in a column. If the OP hadn't been quite so vague then better methods could have been offered.